# Can you have two Animal Crossing: New Leaf files?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

On my 3DS-XL in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* would say new save file I would appreciate anyone who can figure out if you can have a new save file and it will erase the other one. About a month ago I lost my other save file by saying I wanted to recreate the town on accident.

Answer (score 2):

If you created a new save file then the old one is gone. You can not recover it or restore it. Not even from a back up. If you did manage to have the old file backed up, the file will be considered invalid and the system will want to delete it and create a new game if you try to access the old file.

Answer (score -2):

Wrong you can have more than one save file on your animal crossing new leaf game. You can have up to four different people on the same game card or downloaded game. It has been like this since the first animal crossing game. Trust me I know I have three people on my game right now.

Comment: This is not a different save file. It's four characters on the same one.